# Getting "#{Time}" to update on every page reload in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I've searched high and low for what I think should be a simple answer and cant seem to find a solution that works.

This simple app is deployed to heroku: https://inventorylez.herokuapp.com

```
require 'sinatra'

time = Time.now

get '/' do
  "#{time}"
end
```

Sinatra seems to be caching because every time I reload my page the time is not changing. I would like to enable it so that every time I load the page the time will change (avoiding a cache).

thanks in advance

Comment: What is that `time`? Did you mean `Time.now`?

Comment: `"#{time}"` is the same as `time.to_s` which is generally the same as `time` for any given string variable. Where does this value come from?

Comment: sorry guys I had forgot to add in my time variable. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 3):

This value is indeed "cached". It is evaluated once, when your server starts, and then it doesn't have a chance to change. To refresh it, you either need to restart server before each page reload. Or not cache it.

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  Time.now.to_s
end
```

Comment: yes. that was the issue. I was loading my variable outside of the get request. I've re tailored all my code to be inside my get request and things are now updating when I hit the refresh.

Comment: @NickSaltarelli JFYI, here on stackoverflow you thank people by upvoting/accepting their answers :)

Comment: I did but because Im new it hasn't reflected in the public upvote score. I need my reputation to get to 15 first. :)

Comment: @NickSaltarelli: ah, right. Well, you accept anyway, so that others know this answer helped you.